# Convert conditional statement to variable in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the following code which I use in various places

```
  if(!value[field]){
    errors[field] = `${FIELDS[field].errorMessage}`;    
  }
```

Is it possible to set this as a variable in javascript?

I thought of putting this as a property of an object and calling it from there. 
Below is my code

```
   _.each(FIELDS, (type, field) => {
     if (FIELDS[field].validate) {
       if (!value[field]) {
         errors[field] = `${FIELDS[field].errorMessage}`;
       }

       switch (FIELDS[field].formType) {
         case "email":
           if (!/^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i.test(value.email)) {
             errors.email = 'Invalid email address'
           }
         default:
           if (!value[field]) {
             errors[field] = `${FIELDS[field].errorMessage}`;
           }
       }
     }
   });
   return errors;
}
```

Comment: Can you add complete code with demo. [mcve]

Comment: Set what as a variable? Variables do not contain code. Do you mean define it as a function which you can call from "various places"?

Comment: @Tushar I added my demo code

Comment: @torazaburo Yes, I was thinking to do something like this  var check = {
  func :  (function(){...;})() }; but was wondering if there were other methods

Comment: You mean like `var isNotPresent = !value[field];`   and then call it like `if(isNotPresent){...}` ? is that what you mean?

Comment: As a note: please formate your code in a proper way. Having incorrect indentation makes it difficult to understand and read your code.

Answer (score 2):

One thing you could probably try is saving this as a string to a variable and running eval when you need , but it might be a bit slow and issues might come up if your program is asynchronous

```
var condition ="if(!value[field]){errors[field]=`${FIELDS[field].errorMessage}`;}"
```

and then just run eval(condition) for where ever you want it

```
for(var x = 0 ; eval(condition);x++){}
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a function `setError`:

```
function setError() {
  if(!value[field]) {
    errors[field] = `${FIELDS[field].errorMessage}`;    
  }
}
```

Place this inside the arrow function you are passing to `_.each`.

Then each place you want to use it just invoke it:

```
setError();
```

That's what functions are for.

However, as your code stands, you are executing this twice, once at the top, and another time inside the `default` case. Why are you doing that?